Relationship with laravel
I'm trying to make an insert with 4 columns in laravel, but i'm with problems.

Html (form):

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus multiple_add" data="multiplos"></i>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="multiplos">
  <div class="divdefault">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {!! Form::text('protocolo2_guia[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control',]) !!}
      {!! Form::text('protocolo2_convenio[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control',]) !!}
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash multiple_remove" data="multiplos"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Modal Protocolo2

class Protocolo2 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'protocolo2';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = ['_token'];

    public function Users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Users", 'r_auth');
    }

    public function Coperados()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Coperados", 'crm');
    }

    public function Guia()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RProtocolo2Guia::class, 'protocolo2_id', 'id');
    }
}


Modal Relationship

class RProtocolo2Guia extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'r_protocolo2_guia';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
   
    protected $guarded = ['_token'];
   
    protected $fillable = array(
        'protocolo2_id',
        'protocolo2_guia',
        'protocolo2_convenio'
    );
}


Controller

private function insertRelationship($protocolo2, $relationship)
{
    foreach ($relationship as $key => $value) {
        $keyClass = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('', ' ', $key)));
        $value = array_filter($value);
        $class = '\App\RProtocolo2' . $keyClass;
        (new $class())->where('protocolo2_id', $protocolo2->id)->delete();
      
        foreach ($value as $st) {
            $instance = new $class();
            $instance->protocolo2_id = $protocolo2->id;
            $instance->protocolo2_convenio = $protocolo2->protocolo2_convenio;
            $instance->protocolo2_guia = $protocolo2->protocolo2_guia;
            $instance->$key = $st;
            $instance->save();
        }
    }
}



I would like all the information to be included on the same line. It does not recognize the 3rd column "guides"; it only fills in the ID primary key, protocolo2_id Foreign key and the protocolo2_convenio. However, the system does not accept the 4th column which is "protocolo2_guia"...

